# vim: how to replace something only in a column

Tags: vim, replace

I want to replace to symbols ":" and "-" both to tab in the first column of a file:

The input is like:

```
chr1:100-200 1 2 3e-4
chr2:300-400 4 5 6e-4
```

And I want the output to be:

```
chr1 100 200 1 2 3e-4
chr2 300 400 4 5 6e-4
```

I know how to do replacement globally by "%s/:/^I/g" to replace ":" to a tab.

But because some of the entries have numbers in scientific notation such as 3e-4, I can not just use "%s/-/^I/g" to replace "-" to a tab.

Does anyone know how to specify replacement only to the first column?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the global flag, `g`?

Comment: The file has more than 1000 lines and I need to replace the first column in every line so I think I need the global flag.

Comment: Leaving off the global flag will only replace the first occurrence on every line.

Comment: You have a range of `%` which means lines `1`-`$`. Where `$` means the last line. So you are doing a only one substitution for every line in the buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about don't use the g so

```
%s/-/^|/
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use "Ctrl+V", active the "VISUAL BLOCK" mode, select the columns to be changed, press "c", make the change, and then "Esc", it will be applied to all selected columns.

Answer (score 2):

If only the `e` is the problem, you can use `%s/\([^e]\)-/\1^I/g` to find `-`'s not prepend by `e`.

Answer (score 1):

For the special case of the *first* column, you can indeed just leave off the `g` flag. For a general solution that works in any column, establish a *blockwise visual selection* with `<C-v>` (often `<C-q>` on Windows), then restrict the substitution to the visual selection with the `\%V` atom:

```
:%s/\%V-/\t/
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, and, I think, the only correct answer. I was just looking for exactly this answer and did not realise to combine `<C-v>` visual block selection, with `%V` in the replace command. works like a dream. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bunch of regex like:

`:%s/-\(-\)\@!/`  OR `:%s/-.\{-}/`  OR `:%s/-\( .*\)\@!/`  OR `:%s/\%<10c-/`  are useful to replace only the first occurrence of `-` not the second one.

The latest one I think better fits the initial question.